# R: Revolution Analytics max-mem-size?

Tags: memory, r, command-line, configuration-files, max

I can specify the maximum amount of memory used by R or by an object in R with parameters such as

```
--max-mem-size=1400M
```

at command line.
But how can I use it with Revolution Analytics?
I've tried but it seems not no accept any parameter.
I've also tried to look for configuration files, unsuccesfully.

Comment: I could not find anything. I can seen you asked the question [here](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/mem.limits) too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've asked it to Revolution Analytics and they told me it's not possible with RevoIDE.exe.
They will include it on the next reversion.